# angular @NgModule Can't bind to 'model' since it isn't a known property of 'tag'

Tags: angular, typescript

I originally tried to include a shared component in two modules as a declaration.

> BatchStatusComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: DashboardModule and ControlJobModule! Please consider moving...

So I have tried to create a common @NgModule,
I have declared a common module:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        BatchStatusComponent // moved to here
    ]
})
export class SharedComponentsModule { }
```

I have included the above module in a child module as follows

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        SharedComponentsModule, // added module
        DashboardRoutingModule,
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        ChartsModule,
        BsDropdownModule
    ],
    providers: [DashboardApiService, IntegrationSignalService],
    declarations: [        
        DashboardComponent,
        // BatchStatusComponent, // removed from here.
        ServiceStatusComponent,
        StatisticsCounterComponent,
        ClearingDashboardComponent
    ]
})
export class DashboardModule {
}
```

But I am now getting this error:

> Can't bind to 'batchStatuses' since it isn't a known property of 'batch-status'.

1. If 'batch-status' is an Angular component and it has 'batchStatuses' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'batch-status' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

*What am I missing?*

When the component is included as a declaration (in the `DashboardModule`) it works just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to also export the component if you want other modules to see it:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        BatchStatusComponent // moved to here
    ],
    exports: [
        BatchStatusComponent 
    ]
})
export class SharedComponentsModule { }
```

FYI, you can also export entire modules (i.e. CommonModule) so that its available downstream as well.